# Building the ffmpeg Libs as static (.lib) files on Windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, msys2

I've got the build environment set up: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/building-ffmpeg-windows-without-fuss-moshe-david

From this I can successfully build ffmpeg.exe but I want to build libavcodec.lib etc statically for use with my project. I assume it's just a simple command line option for ./configure that I'm missng, but
`--enable-static` builds the exe and `--enable-shared` builds the dlls...

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Best,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the libraries (.a) files were being produced anyway and were in the respective folders. These work on windows of course, and can be copied out and linked in your project.